# Software for Mac OS X Leopard to track and record network usage

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, network-monitoring

I'm looking for a program that I can install on a Mac that will tell me how many bytes I download each day, and store that info in such a way that I could later view the results.

Limiting by ports (80, 443, 21, 22) would be awesome as well.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a local web proxy, then analyze the logs.

It's simple to download and install [SquidMan](http://homepage.mac.com/adg/SquidMan/index.html), which is a point and click
way of enabling the squid web proxy on your system.

You will have to configure your machine to go through the proxy on localhost
instead of directly to the website.  You can find this in advanced tab of
your network interface in  System Preferences -> Network

Then, you can analyze the logs and see not only how much you've downloaded, but also
what and when.

Answer (score 0):

Type 'man tcpdump' in a terminal.

Comment: tcpdump is useful, but you have to do all kinds of things to the data... processing, parsing, pruning. Not fun.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't a complete package or anything, but netstat will show you bytes
transmitted on an interface

```
netstat -ib
```

you can record this somewhere every day.  "man netstat" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool for this is [ethernal](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~jbovet/ethernal.html) but it hasn't been updated for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [these two apps](http://homepage.mac.com/rominar/net.html), Net Monitor and Net Monitor Sidekick, the first to do what you describe (with a calculator to determine throughput over a date range), the second to track traffic by host.  After trying to use [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/), which is horrible to set up, hideous to use, and very, very limited, I'm thrilled =)